# Add new Hazelcast member after HazelcastInstance has been created

Tags: hazelcast

I'm trying to add a new member to my newly created HazelcastInstance (after it has been initialized) but I cannot find the API to do so. I don't want to use Multicast, so I disabled it, here's the code:

```
Config config = new Config();
config.getNetworkConfig().getJoin().getMulticastConfig().setEnabled(false);
HazelcastInstance instance = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(config);
```

I tried adding the members to the config after initialization, but it doesn't seem to do anything:

```
instance.getConfig().getNetworkConfig().getJoin().getTcpIpConfig().addMember("192.168.1.5");
```

The code above works if I call it before the Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(config) method has been invoked, but this is not a solution for me, as I want to have a running instance and I don't know the IP (or range) of the new member that should be added later on.

I'm not sure if this is the correct way to approach this, so any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define the Network Config and you should be knowing the list of IP addresses between which the Cluster would be communicating.
Otherwise, you can just start a cluster by running multiple Hazelcast instances in a single machine/localhost itself.
Please note that if you want your multiple instances to join and form a cluster, all the instances should be sharing the same configuration, otherwise they will form their own cluster. So best thing is to define the configuration in hazelcast.xml. If you want programmatic way, then you can follow below example.

```
    Config config = new Config();
    NetworkConfig network = config.getNetworkConfig();
    network.getJoin().getMulticastConfig().setEnabled(false);
    network.getJoin().getTcpIpConfig().setEnabled(true);
    network.setPortAutoIncrement(true);
    network.setPort(33001);
    network.getJoin().getTcpIpConfig().addMember("127.0.0.1");

    HazelcastInstance hz1 = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(config);
    HazelcastInstance hz2 = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(config);
```

The above code would start two instances in localhost within same JVM.

```
Jun 24, 2016 4:35:42 PM com.hazelcast.cluster.ClusterService
INFO: [127.0.0.1]:33001 [dev] [3.5] 
Members [2] {
    Member [127.0.0.1]:33001 this
    Member [127.0.0.1]:33002
}
Jun 24, 2016 4:35:44 PM com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService
INFO: [127.0.0.1]:33002 [dev] [3.5] Address[127.0.0.1]:33002 is STARTED
```

Another way is to just remove the hz2 line and run the same config again in its own JVM. Both will join and form a cluster.

Comment: The instances that I want to setup in a cluster, are not on the same JVM and not on the same host. When the first instance starts, I still don't know the IP address of the second instance. I need to instantiate hz1 (without setting the remote member, because I don't know its IP) and after that, add the new member when I get the host IP.

Comment: You will have to define the IP address in the initial stage itself. Otherwise the previous members will not have any to identify the new members and the new members will start its own cluster, as it will be a different configuration.  
Another possible solution is to make use of wildcards in the configuration.  
`<tcp-ip enabled="true">
        <interface>192.168.1.0-7</interface>
        <interface>192.168.1.*</interface>
    </tcp-ip>`

Answer (score 4):

Another option is to write your own DiscoveryStrategy: http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.6/manual/html-single/index.html#discovery-spi

Anyhow in all the cases Hazelcast will only request new members at certain intervals. There is no way to "add new members" and it normally is not required as new members join the existing cluster, therefore new members need to know about old members but not the other way around.

Comment: It makes sense, otherwise there may be data collision if the "new cluster" joins the already established one.

Comment: Tested this and it works when nodes are dynamically added. Hazelcast takes its own sweet time to notice the changes though. 5 minutes in my test case. This resolves the split-brain scenario that can happen when instances start in parallel and are not registered with the cloud service discovery mechanism when the cache is initialised.

Comment: It shouldn't be like 5mins but 3mins or smt like that, however it is configurable, see System Properties in the docs :)

Answer (score 1):

The question says:

```
instance.getConfig().getNetworkConfig().getJoin().getTcpIpConfig().addMember("192.168.1.5")
```

doesn't work. However, in my experience (using version 3.7.1) it does work. Not immediately, but within a minute or so the new member is added to the cluster, and I guess the lag is the `interval` @nocatrius mentions.

Worth mentioning the members are on different hosts and otherwise config is as it is in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Borrowing from another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41453332/hazelcast-programmatic-configuration-of-tcp-ip-is-no-adding-members-in-cluster/45745402#45745402) 
To test member(s) and client locally on the same interface, I had to
1. Instruct HZ
    System.setProperty("hazelcast.socket.server.bind.any", "false");
    System.setProperty("hazelcast.socket.bind.any", "false");
2. Add desired interface
    config.getNetworkConfig().getInterfaces().setEnabled(true).addInterface( memberNodeDefinition.getParameters().get("192.168.1.0") );

Regarding above mentioned property, a periodic check for new members, it is actually 5 minutes in version 3.9. I found this controls it:

```
System.setProperty("hazelcast.merge.first.run.delay.seconds", "5")
```

Answer (score 0):

henryw374 and Vortex's answers worked for me as well.  I can report that the properties hazelcast.socket.server.bind.any and hazelcast.socket.bind.any were not necessary to set.  As mentioned hazelcast.merge.first.run.delay.seconds hazelcast.merge.next.run.delay.seconds is also configurable.  In my case integrating Hazelcast as an level 2 cache for Hibernate requires initializing Hazelcast with Hibernate before the cluster configuration is known.  After setting the Hazelcast instance name in hibernate.cfg.xml, and setting the server's own IP and interface in hazelcast.xml, all that was needed later to add nodes, that is, join a cluster, are:

```
HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance = Hazelcast.getHazelcastInstanceByName('hazelcast-hibernate-instance');
hazelcastInstance.getConfig().getNetworkConfig().getJoin().getTcpIpConfig().setEnabled(true).addMember('x.x.x.x')
```